# How can I kill omxplayer player on a Raspberry Pi using Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, omxplayer

I'm doing a DIY project using a Raspberry Pi 3 where I need to play 4 videos using omxplayer.

Each video is played once you press a certain button on the protoboard:

- Press Button 1 - Play Video 1
- Press Button 2 - Play Video 2
- Press Button 3 - Play Video 3
- Press Button 4 - Play Video 4

I was successful playing the 4 videos whenever I press any of the buttons using the following python code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)   # Declaramos que los pines seran llamados como numeros
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN)  # GPIO  7 como entrada
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN) # GPIO 17 como entrada
GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.IN) # GPIO 27 como entrada
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.IN) # GPIO 22 como entrada

pathVideos = "/home/pi/VideoHD/Belen"                   # Directorio donde se encuentran los videos en HD

def reproducirVideos(nameVideo):
    command = "omxplayer -p -o hdmi %s/%s.mp4" % (pathVideos,nameVideo)
    os.system(command)
    print "Reproduciendo el Video: %s " % nameVideo

def programaPrincipal():
    print("Inicio")

    while True:
        if (GPIO.input(4)):
            print("Iniciando Video: AMANECER")
            reproducirVideos("amanecer")
        elif (GPIO.input(17)):
            print("Iniciando Video: DIA")
            reproducirVideos("dia")
        elif (GPIO.input(27)):
            print("Iniciando Video: ATARDECER")
            reproducirVideos("atardecer")
        elif (GPIO.input(22)):
            print("Iniciando Video: ANOCHECER")
            reproducirVideos("anochecer")
        else:
            pass
    print("Fin de programa")
    GPIO.cleanup() #Limpiar los GPIO  


programaPrincipal()                           #Llamamos a la funcion blinkLeds para ejecutar el programa
```

Here is my issue.

When I press a button e.g Button 1, the whole video 1 starts playing properly on the screen. If I press any button while the video1 is running, nothing happens. What I want to achieve is that whenever I press any button on the protoboard, omxplayer should stop reproducing any video (if the is any playing) and start a new one.

I have read something about kill omxplayer using PIPE like they say in the following link but without success:

[How can I kill omxplayer by Python Subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871658/how-can-i-kill-omxplayer-by-python-subprocess)

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

A bit hacky i guess but have you tried to killall before running the omxplayer?

```
command = "killall omxplayer; omxplayer -p -o hdmi %s/%s.mp4" % (pathVideos,nameVideo)
os.system(command)
```

Comment: Thank you Matz! Despite the above code was not working as intended. It took me to another solution that worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

I modified **reproducirVideos()** function with the following code in order to kill any process of **omxplayer**

```
def reproducirVideos(nameVideo):
    command1 = "sudo killall -s 9 omxplayer.bin"
    os.system(command1)
    command2 = "omxplayer -p -o hdmi %s/%s.mp4 &" % (pathVideos,nameVideo)
    os.system(command2)
    print "Reproduciendo el Video: %s " % nameVideo
```

I also added **&** at the end of **command2** in order to get the command run on the background

A Little bit "hacky" but worked properly for me :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to give the video a session ID so you can kill the process by ID later. Here's a simple video repeater :

```
import os, signal, subprocess
import pifacedigitalio as pfd
from time import sleep

# Import movie names from /home/pi/video in alphabetical order. Note that movie 0 will loop when another is not playing.
names = [f for f in os.listdir('/home/pi/video') if os.path.isfile(os.path.join('/home/pi/video', f))]
movies = ['/home/pi/video/{name}'.format(name=name) for name in names]
movies.sort()

pfd.init()
loopMovie = 0
sleep (10)

# Start first instance of movie 0. Note that all processes started get a session ID so they can all be killed together with killpg.
# Add '-o', 'local' to the omxplayer operators to get local audio (headphone jack) instead of HDMI
playProcess=subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer','-b',movies [loopMovie]], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, preexec_fn=os.setsid)

while True :
   # One piFace import board has 8 inputs numbered 0-7
   for b in range (8) :
      if pfd.digital_read(b) == 1 and b + 1 < len(movies) :
         if playProcess.poll() != 0 : os.killpg(os.getpgid(playProcess.pid), signal.SIGTERM)
         playProcess=subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer','-b', '-o', 'local', movies [b+1]], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
   # if nothing is playing, restart movie 0.
   if playProcess.poll() == 0 :
      playProcess=subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer','-b',movies [0]], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
   sleep (.1)
```